# Antlr Python Error

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, grammar

I am trying to generate the parse tree for the Antlr grammar in Python.

My code:

```
char_stream = InputStream('a(1)')
lexer = MLexer(char_stream )
stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = MParser(stream)
tree = parser.start()
```

Error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'a' expecting <INVALID>
```

When I checked the generated parser file by Antlr:

```
 literalNames = [ "<INVALID>", "' '", "'\t'", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", 
                 "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", 
                 "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", 
                 "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", 
                 "':-'", "','", "'('", "')'", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", 
                 "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", 
                 "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "'.'" ]

     symbolicNames = [ "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "<INVALID>", "DATALOGPROGRAM", 
                  "SCHEMALIST", "SCHEMA", "CLAUSELIST", "RULELIST", 
                  "FACTLIST", "GOALLIST", "FACT", "E_RULE", "GOAL", 
                  "BODY", "LITERALLIST", "LITERAL", "PREDICATE", "GOALSIGN", 
                  "COMMA", "LEFTBRAK", "RIGHTBRAK", "OPERATOR", "VARIABLELIST", 
                  "VARIABLE", "CONSTANTLIST", "CONSTANT", "Numbers", 
                  "Lrr", "Urr", "PERIOD" ]
```

There are so many Invalids in the antlr generated parser file. How do I fix this?

Please find the following grammar in Antlr:
There are lot of "Invalid" in Symbolic Names and Literal Names

```
grammar N;


start               : DATALOGPROGRAM;

LITERAL             :  LEFTBRAK (VARIABLELIST) RIGHTBRAK;

PREDICATE            :Lrr  (Lrr|Urr)+;


GOALSIGN            : ':-';

COMMA               : ',';

LEFTBRAK            : '(';

RIGHTBRAK            : ')';

OPERATOR            :  '>' | '<' | '=' | '!='  | '>=' | '<=' ;

VARIABLELIST        : VARIABLE | VARIABLE (COMMA VARIABLE)*;

VARIABLE            : Urr | Urr (Lrr|Urr)+;   /

CONSTANTLIST        : CONSTANT | CONSTANT (COMMA CONSTANT)*;

CONSTANT            : Lrr | Lrr (Lrr|Urr)+| Numbers ; //Constant must start with Lowercase letter

Numbers             : DIGIT;

Lrr : LOWERCASE;

Urr: UPPERCASE;

PERIOD              : '.';


fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;

 fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;

 fragment DIGIT      : [0-9] ;

 whitespace : (' ' | '\t') ;
```

Comment: Post your grammar here or (if it is too long) give us a link to a place where you have stored it, so we can see how the tokens are defined.

Comment: "expecting <INVALID>" usually means that you're using a token rule that's impossible to match (possibly because it conflicts with another token rule). Beyond that, we can't help you without seeing the grammar. So I second Mike's suggestion, except that if the grammar is too long to post here, you should post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not a link to the whole grammar.

Comment: Hello, I have added the grammar to the post.

Comment: You define `start: DATALOGPROGRAM`, but then you don't define `DATALOGPROGRAM`. Other issues I've noticed are that `PREDICATE` overlaps with `CONSTANT`, so the first two alternatives of `CONSTANT` won't have an effect; and that your `LIST` rules should almost certainly not be lexer rules (they obviously overlap with the items they're lists of; plus I'd expect you'd want to allow whitespace between elements of a list). I strongly suggest you revisit your learning materials until you understand where to user lexer rules and where parser rules.

Comment: If you provide a small sample of the Datalog grammar (???) that you want to parse, I could show a starting example of ANTLR grammar to put you on the right track.

Comment: There is a discrepancy between the error you have posted and what I obtain by running the posted grammar : `$ grun N start -tokens -diagnostics input.txt` (which contains `a(1)`) gives `[@0,0:0='a',<CONSTANTLIST>,1:0] ... line 1:0 mismatched input 'a' expecting DATALOGPROGRAM`. How did you run it ?

Comment: @BernardK He probably ran it by running the Python code shown in the question (plus the missing import statements). I think replacing name of unmatchable tokens with `<INVALID>` is a quirk of the Python bindings.

Comment: @sepp2k Sorry, I missed it. If I run a Java equivalent `main` program, I obtain the same error message `line 1:0 mismatched input 'a' expecting DATALOGPROGRAM`.

Comment: And the generated parser contains `private static final String[] _SYMBOLIC_NAMES = {null, null, null, "LITERAL", "PREDICATE", "GOALSIGN", "COMMA", "LEFTBRAK", ...`, so @AjaySanthosh, don't worry about these `<INVALID>`. Thera are always a few `null`'s. + Maybe you prefer to find by yourself, it's more pedagogical, but if you are in a dead end, I have a ready grammar based on yours, just waiting to adapt the start rule to an example of real input to parse (e.g. the goal Datalog rule).

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed the grammar now.